# What are the names of the breakfast spreads used in Indian cuisine?

Tags: sauce, indian-cuisine, breakfast

I visited Bangalore a few years ago and much enjoyed some of the hotel breakfast dishes.  As I remember they were a sort of paste that could be spread onto bread or toast, etc. I have no idea what they are called or how to make them.

Could someone suggest what they were and how I could make something similar?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit, since there are a lot of spreads? What colour was it? What consistency? How did it taste?

Comment: Mildly spicy but not hot, spreadable but not solid, as I recall. It was some time ago now and I don't really remember; just that they were very tasty.  Ecuador is, oddly, a bit of a culinary desert from my perspective (unless you like things like steamed pig skin and endless chicken soup).

Comment: Are you talking about the different kind of chutneys?

Comment: Are they really tasty on bread etc? If so, then maybe that is what they were.

Answer (score 1):

Well chutneys are not really eaten with bread. They are eaten with breakfast dishes such as Dosa, Idli, Vada etc. But they might go really well with bread as well. Refer [this link](http://indiancooking.hubpages.com/hub/10-Tasty-Indian-Chutney-Recipes-how-to-prepare) for an idea about how to prepare chutneys

Answer (score 0):

I have had toast with Kaya in Malaysia - it is a sweet spread that can be used with butter or on its own.

Answer (score 0):

could be a variety of chutneys. Mint and ginger are usually pretty common. other varieties are coriander, peanut and coconut.

Answer (score 0):

If I may be pardoned, the non-use of bread with chutneys is a bit of mindset matter.
Of course the yeast's CO2 sourish fermentation smell factor, the milkbread's sweetishness are the off-putting elements in the bread-chutney combo development. Add to it the soggyish [vs.idly] noncrisp [compared to dosa,paratha] and the case gets closed.

With the advent of toasted sandwiches and the like this has been mitigated a bit.
Still, the fluffy steaming idly, and the crisp hot dosa, vada -even softy pongal upma with the spicy fumes intoxicating you, attract the chutneys and sambar as a proverbial duck to the water.

Nowadays, with the multigrain breads and with the old sandwich bread thinly sliced and goldentoasted to a crisp crunch, the use of a ginger-tamarind-red/green chilly salted seasoned paste at a stand-on the finger cosistency goes well. 
So does the well-soaked-in-ghee-dalpowder (chick pea, moong dal roasted and ground with asafoetida salt chillypowder), the pure fire kaarampodi, with the smouldering roasted ground coriander,cummin, chilly, salt with a touch of tamarind and drenched in ghee does spice up the bland wimpy bread into ferocious fighting cock.
And, of course, the gatti chutney (meaning the chutney without the extra flowing consistency) made of coconut or peanut or onion-ginger-garlic-chilly serves as a good blood thinner wakeup for the deserving wodgs too (western oriented desi gent)

Try and visit a whole new world of westernised breakfast accompaniment.